# Function calling in a for loop

Tags: javascript, processing

This assignment is required to be pop art and I have decided I am going to use pokeballs. We must use 2 for loops: one for the top row, one for the bottom and create a function. The issue I am having is how to create 2 more pokeballs in the top row (there will be 6 pokeballs total: 3 on top and 3 on bottom) that will be random colors while using a function call to do so.

```javascript
var RANDCOL = random(0, 400);
var XBALL = 65;
var YBALL = 108;

//dividing tiles
fill(250, 0, 0);
rect(0, 0, 130, 200);
fill(0, 187, 255);
rect(131, 0, 137, 200);
fill(0, 0, 0);
rect(269, 0, 130, 200);
fill(167, 158, 235);
rect(0, 200, 131, 199);
fill(46, 184, 101);
rect(131, 200, 137, 199);
fill(255, 0, 0);
rect(269, 200, 130, 199);

//pokeball specifications
var pokeBall = function(x) {
    stroke(158, 214, 235);
    ellipse(XBALL, YBALL, 99, 97);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    line(15, 109, 56, 109);
    line(116, 109, 72, 109);
    ellipse(64, 108, 19, 16);
};

//loop for top row
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var x = i * 134;
    fill(RANDCOL);
    pokeBall();
}
```

Comment: Why is var x used for ,also specify your expected output

Comment: var x  = i * 134 is supposed to take the first pokeball and loop it 2 more times to the other 2 squares and the x parameter in the function was something I was merely playing around with to see if it did anything. Here is a google image of what it is supposed to look like except there will be 3 rows not 2. [image](https://www.google.com/search?q=pop+art+pokeballs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiczKzsk47QAhUUSGMKHZ6BA7kQ_AUICCgB&biw=1920&bih=943#imgrc=mruoTaTG6KZ_lM%3A)

Comment: It's really just the loop im having trouble with. I am trying this at the moment: `for(var y = 3; y <= 3; y++) { 
for(var x = 3; x <= 3; x++) {   
    fill(RANDCOL);
    pokeBall();

}

}`

Comment: Maybe I just need to take a break. This is what I am leaving for the time being until I come back refreshed. `for(var x = 0; x < 3; x++) { 
for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    fill(RANDCOL);
    pokeBall();


}
}`

Answer (score 0):

First off, this code doesn't run, because you're using Processing functions before the `setup()` function is called. Please try to post code as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to run.

Anyway, to accomplish your goal, your `pokeBall()` function needs to take arguments specifying the position of the ball, and you need to draw the ball based on those coordinates. You're **almost** doing that now by using the `XBALL` and `YBALL` variables, but you need to convert those into arguments and pass those in from the `for` loops you're describing.

Here's an example. Let's say I have this function:

```
function drawBall(){
   ellipse(100, 150, 20, 20);
}
```

That function always draws a circle at coordinate `100,150`. I could change that to use arguments instead:

```
function drawBall(ballX, ballY){
   ellipse(ballX, ballY, 20, 20);
}
```

And then I could call that function and pass in arguments to draw the circle in multiple places:

```
drawBall(100, 200);
drawBall(200, 300);
drawBall(60, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to call the function only one time in a for loop so the loop would draw it 3 times instead of having to call the function 3 times? Because I think calling the function 3 times defeats the purpose of having a for loop, no?

Comment: Like, I am trying to do this so the pokeball is spread out 134 x-units but the for loop doesn't execute at all and I have tried many different things. `for(var x = 0; x <= 3; x++) { 
  var x_one = pokeBall * 134;
    
    
    fill(random(0,400), random(0,400), random(0,400), random(0, 400));
    pokeBall(68, 107, x_one);`

Comment: @Smokeyflo My calling the function three times was just an example. You can absolutely call it from a `for` loop.

Comment: Okay thanks. Sorry to pester you but could you maybe give me another hint as to why my loop wouldn't be working? I feel like the logic in my loop is correct.

Comment: @Smokeyflo You aren't pestering me, I like answering questions. If you have follow-up questions, you should post them as new questions in their own posts. But I will say that your loop never actually uses the `x` variable, so the ball will always be drawn in the same place.

Comment: Thank you. I will roll with that and see what I can do.

Comment: YESS. I got it to loop the top row so thats done. Now I need to get it to loop through the bottom rows which is a completely different demon and only have 30 mins to figure it out Q.Q

Comment: @Smokeyflo Just think about exactly where you want the balls to show up. Which value changes from the top row to the bottom row?

Comment: The 'y' changes. So I need to write another for loop using a different variable and plug in different numbers.. I think. Need to mess with it.

Comment: @Smokeyflo Sounds like a plan! Good luck!

Comment: GOT IT!!!! The main problem was that I needed to add i + and j + to my x and y values of my pokeball function. That was so easy I can't believe I was thinking so hard about that.

Comment: @Smokeyflo Hahaha that sure sounds like programming to me!